# How to track the date and time when AD users last accessed/mapped a shared folder

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I am trying to get a list of all users defined in the Windows Server with the date-time of the last time it either logged in to the server or mapped/accessed a file share.
to do that I tried the following script:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=whatever,dc=local" -ResultPageSize 0 -Prop CN,samaccountname,LastLogonTimestamp | Select CN,samaccountname,@{N='Last‌Logon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp)}}
```

Which provided me with the following output:

```
CN                             samaccountname                Last‌Logon                  
--                             --------------                -----------                  
Administrador                  Administrador                 08/02/2019 17:30:00          
Invitado                       Invitado                      01/01/1601 1:00:00           
krbtgt                         krbtgt                        01/01/1601 1:00:00           
Maite                          maite                         01/01/1601 1:00:00           
Mari Carmen                    mcarmen                       01/01/1601 1:00:00           
Emilio                         emilio                        01/01/1601 1:00:00           
Erica                          erica                         01/01/1601 1:00:00
```

I know for a fact that the users other than Administrator have accessed the server file shares (some of them map them as drives every day) but the only valid logon date obtained in the list is for Adminstrator.

It seems like this command is only reporting when a user actually logs into the server through RDP or the console.

How can I get a similar query to report each time a user accessed any of the servers shares?

Comment: I feel like you would be better suited to enable file level and share level auditing on the servers. Then query the audit logs for the data you want. If you send the logs to a robust log collection engine, it may even have real-time triggers you can configure. You could send them to the event log for example and set up subscriptions from a central log server although I have not necessarily liked that solution in the past personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You file share access creates a Network Logon (Logon Type 3) which doesn't affect the `LastLogon` attribute (and `LastLogonTimestamp` respectively). In this case you will have to obtain the information from the Domain Controllers event log, where all logons are logged. The following script will output the last logon date of any user with its logon type of the last 24h.

```
#86400000 = 24h
$FilterXPath = '*[System[EventID=4624 and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 86400000]]]' 
$LogonEvents = Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -FilterXPath $FilterXPath

$Logons = foreach ($LogonEvent in $LogonEvents) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        LogonDate = $LogonEvent.TimeCreated
        UserName = $LogonEvent.Properties[5].Value
        UserDomain = $LogonEvent.Properties[6].Value
        LogonType = $LogonEvent.Properties[8].Value
    }
}

$LogonsGroupedByUserName = $Logons | Group-Object -Property UserName

foreach ($Group in $LogonsGroupedByUserName) {     
    $Group.Group | 
        Sort-Object -Property LogonDate -Descending | 
        Select-Object -First 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. It does not really help me in this case since the Atttribute I am using is the LastLogonTimestamp (which is replicated). On the other hand, I only have one Domain controller which is also the file server. My problems really is the fact that the users that simply access the network drives do not seem to be updating this parameter. Most users use a local windows user but when they access the share they need to identify themselves using the AD user (I know .. this is something we should change... )

Comment: Right, I didn't notice you are using `LogonTimeStamp` in your query. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I had to make a change into the FilterXpath line definition because it did not take it as is. I simply removed the TimeCreated restriction and left it as: $FilterXPath = '*[System[EventID=4624]]'